# removing the 'title' field from custom content types

Tags: nodes

I've created a content type to manage people, but in addition to the 'first name' and 'last name' fields that I've created, there's a 'title' field that seems to be present because its a Node module element.

Is there any way to, say, auto-fill it with something and hide it so that users who add content don't have to worry about it? It seems so redundant to have them fill out 'title' in addition to first name and last name.

Comment: can you please explain more on what you are trying do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Exclude Node Title](https://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module

> This module handles a very simple functionality, decide whatever to
>   ***exclude a node title*** from full node page or node teasers. It provides
>   a ***checkbox*** on node-edit pages for easier exclusion, or you can use the
>   admin page to manually enter a list of node id's to exclude title.

Also provides the option to hide all titles of a certain Content type.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need this [automatic nodetitle](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle). Please give a search in google before posting here.To prevent empty content title fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.